# Groups where every non-identity element is of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G\cong H$ are isomorphic groups whose non-identity elements are all of order 2. Fix $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ with $g\neq 1$ and $h\neq 1$. My question is does there exist an isomorphism from $G$ to $H$ taking $g$ to $h?$

My guess is that we can construct such an isomorphism from the given one, but I haven't quite been able to make this work, so maybe it is not true?

Comment: If the groups are finite, yes; if the groups are infinite and you assume the Axiom of Choice, yes; if the groups are infinite and you don’t assume the Axiom of Choice, then I don’t know but suspect the answer will be “no”.

Comment: As a hint: such a group is a vector space over the field with two elements.

Comment: I suppose the groups are finite. Then see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576231/g-a-group-s-t-every-non-identity-element-has-order-2-if-g-is-finite-prove) how to construct $G\cong C_2^n\cong H$ with $g\mapsto h$.